# Not getting all records while exporting SQL Server data to Excel in console application in .net

Tags: .net, sql-server, c#-4.0, console-application, excel-interop

I'm not able to get all the rows into an Excel while exporting from SQL Server. While running the code, I'm only getting the top 4 and last 4 rows, somehow the code is picking up 8 rows, I'm not able to find out issue.

[image: select * from Employees]

Summary :

1. I'm using a T-SQL pagination query to extract data from SQL Server in batches in a console application
2. provided the select query image link for my sample data.

Code:

```
namespace ExportToExcelConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            string connString = @"Data Source=NIKKU;Initial Catalog=AnuragDB;Integrated Security=True";
            string query = "select * from Employees";

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            conn.Open();
            conn.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the no of rows u want to fetch at a time = ");

            int nrows = 4;         // Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int timesbatchruns = 4;    // RecordCount / nrows;
            int startrows = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("timesbatchruns = " + timesbatchruns + "   startrows = " + startrows + "   nrows = " + nrows);
            Console.ReadKey();

            int counter = 1;

            while (counter <= timesbatchruns)
            {
                p.ExportDataSetToExcel(startrows, nrows,counter);
                startrows = startrows + nrows;
                counter = counter + 1;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("dfdfdff");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private void ExportDataSetToExcel(int a1, int a2, int counter)
        {
            int PageNumber = a1;
            int RowsPerPage = a2;
            int m = counter;

            string connString = @"Data Source=NIKKU;Initial Catalog=AnuragDB;Integrated Security=True";
            string query = "Select * from Employees  order by EmpId offset " + PageNumber + " Rows Fetch Next " + RowsPerPage + " Rows only";

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            conn.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            sda.Fill(ds);

            // Create an Excel application instance'
            Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();

            //Create an Excel workbook instance and open it from the predefined location
            Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\\New7.xlsx");

            foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {
                //Add a new worksheet to workbook with the Datatable name
                if (m == 1)
                {
                    Excel.Worksheet excelWorkSheet = excelWorkBook.Sheets.Add();
                    excelWorkSheet.Name = table.TableName;
                    Console.WriteLine(table.TableName);

                    for (int i = 1; i < table.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                    {
                        excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, i] = table.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
                    }

                    for (int j = 0; j < table.Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k < table.Columns.Count; k++)
                        {
                            excelWorkSheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1] = table.Rows[j].ItemArray[k].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var excelWorkSheet = excelWorkBook.Sheets[table.TableName];
                    Console.WriteLine(table.TableName);

                    for (int j = 0; j < table.Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k < table.Columns.Count; k++)
                        {
                            excelWorkSheet.Cells[j + a2 + 2, k + 1] = table.Rows[j].ItemArray[k].ToString();
                            Console.WriteLine(table.Rows[j].ItemArray[k].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(RowsPerPage + " rows fetching done");
                excelWorkBook.Save();
                excelWorkBook.Close();
                excelApp.Quit();

                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue");
                Console.ReadKey();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the incomplete output I'm currently getting :

[image: Incomplete output]

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: @Alex   yes i tried...while running it is reading all the values from 1 to 14 but inserting only first 4 and last 4 rows